# Best way to export an image in multiple formats using GIMP's batch scripting in the same script?

Tags: scheme, gimp

I am trying to automate creating copies of a GIMP image in different formats, in order to serve them on a website (Using the picture element, offering several versions of an image for compatibility).  So I've been trying to build a script to do this so I don't have to manually export each image, as well as enable myself to define my own defaults for images.

So far, I have been able to cobble together a script that does accomplish most of my goals:

```
(define (hugo-image-processing filename)
  (
    let* (
      (image (car (gimp-file-load 1 (string-append filename ".xcf") (string-append filename ".xcf"))))
      (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))))
    (file-png-save-defaults 1 image drawable (string-append filename ".png") (string-append filename ".png"))
    (file-heif-av1-save 1 image drawable (string-append filename ".avif") (string-append filename ".avif") 100 1)
    (file-webp-save 1 image drawable (string-append filename ".webp") (string-append filename ".webp") 0 1 100 100 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1)
    (gimp-image-delete image)
  )
)
```

This works, and image are exported in expected formats, but I noticed that the size of my output files vary based on the order that the images are saved.  In the above case, my test image exports as an AVIF file at 139 kB while my WebP file weighs in at 76 kB.  If I swap the order, and save the AVIF file after the WebP file, the WebP file still contains 76 kB, but the AVIF file is now 58 kB in size.

This behavior can be seen if one moves the file-png-save-defaults as well (though WebP stays a consistent 76 kB in any order).

I'm guessing that the file--save commands are modifying either the image or the drawable, but I haven't quite figured out why.  I'm not terribly familiar with Scheme, so my ability to troubleshoot this beyond observing this behavior is limited. Any input on this issue would be appreciated.

I run this command `gimp-2.10 -i -b "(hugo-image-processing \"working\")" -b "(gimp-quit 0)"` to call the script, and I am using Gimp 2.10.30 on Windows 11.

Comment: Can't reproduce (same MD5 for AVIF and WEBP if I swap the two save operations) using Gimp 2.10.21 in which the HEIF function is `file-heif-save` with the same parameters as yours. What is your Gimp version and OS? And why are you saving the Webp as an animation?

Comment: Tried with a smaller image that looks more like what you would save as a PNG (text and some color) (previous was a photo). Same results, except that the Webp is smaller than the Avif in this case (on the photo the Avif was the smaller one)

Comment: Really good questions, I'm trying to get this script to work on windows 11 using GIMP 2.10.30.  I actually thought I wasn't saving the image as an animation ('1' seems to disable some features, and I wasn't sure of the default for those properties), so thanks for the heads up on that.  Also, I chose PNG as a generic broadly accepted lossless format, if you have a better suggestion for the main fallback image format I'll take it.

Comment: Hmm. The one difference is that I use `file-heif-save` and not `file-heif-av1-save`. My Gimp is missing the latter, possibly because I didn't enable it when compiling it. `file-heif-av1-save` is fairly recent and could have a bug (unless it's `file-webp-save` (btw, did you fix the animation argument))?

Comment: I also tested this script with the ```file-heif-save``` method, and was still experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: Zeroing out the animation properties worked.  Still not exactly sure why (Does it add the animation information to the drawable between saves?), but I can work with this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, the problem appears to come from a spurious "save as animation" flag in the `file-webp-save` call. Possibly a bug in 2.10.30, that I cannot reproduce in my 2.10.24, even with the animation flag.

I tested the problem with the following code:

```
def fullname(name,extension):
    return "/tmp/"+name+"."+extension

def savemulti(image):
    xcf=fullname(image,"xcf")
    png=fullname(image,"png")
    avif=fullname(image,"avif")
    webp=fullname(image,"webp")
    image=pdb.gimp_file_load(xcf,xcf)
    drawable=image.active_layer
    pdb.file_png_save_defaults(image,drawable,png,png)
    pdb.file_webp_save(image,drawable,webp,webp,0, 1, 100, 100,1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    pdb.file_heif_save(image,drawable,avif,avif,100,1)
    gimp.Display(image) # Start an image window
```

(which at the end start a Gimp window with the image in it instead of deleting the image).

Copy-paste in the python-fu console, after editing the `fullname(...)` function, and invoke as `savemulti("TestImage")`. When the windows comes up, you can check the Layers list and see if there are extra layers by any chance...